# How to get a link to a Google Translate web page translation?

Tags: google-translate

I would like to put an hyperlink to a webpage which will be automatically translated on opening using the Google Translate API.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&sl=auto&tl=TARGET_LANGUAGE_CODE&u=URL_TO_THE_WEBPAGE_TO_TRANSLATE" target="_blank">WEB_PAGE_TITLE</a>
```